# Updating Slack Home Tab In Mobile (views.publish) After view_submission From Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, slack, slack-api

What is the proper way to update the home tab on the Slack mobile app after a modal sends a view_submission event? FWIW, the home tab updates on the web UI but on mobile it does not and the person has to click away from the home tab and then back on it to update it.

Here is the flow I'm using:

1. Modal is opened and person submits form from modal.
2. Modal sends **view_submission** to my app.
3. My app sends `{'response_action': 'clear'}`.
4. My app posts home tab layout to `views.publish`.

I'm expecting the home tab layout to update. On the web UI it does update, but on the Slack mobile app it does not update. On the mobile app you have to tap to another section (eg Messages tab or another conversation) and then back to the home tab for the update to happen.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm have the same and am noticing the same issue (home tab updates on web but you have to switch threads and come back for the update to show)

Comment: I did not find a solution. I contacted Slack about this and they confirmed that this is indeed a bug but they have not given me an update nor have provided me with an ETA of when it may be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A work around (or maybe the correct way to do it depending on how you interpret Slack's documentation) is to return the acknowledgement response when you get the view_submission request from slack **BEFORE** you make a post request to `view.publish`.

Generally speaking, the simplest way to process the flow above is to take the `view_submission` data, figure out what updates need to be made, post the update via `views.publish`, and then return the acknowledgement response `{'response_action': 'clear'}`  all in a single synchronous process. This works as expected on web, but not on mobile. Instead, however, if you break it into two steps and use a job queue or other asynchronous system to offload the processing of the `view_submission` data and posting the update via `views.publish` and immediately return the acknowledgement response then it works as expected on web and mobile. For performance reasons you'll just want to make sure that the `view_submission` data gets processed immediately after returning the acknowledgement response.